# How to validate remote data in a client?

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, mvvm, client-side

I'm designing a client-server system, and i need to understand how to check if the client's data is correct when they send operations and requests. In this particular case, i've got a browser and a javascript client that gets data from longpolling and updates a series of objects wich get binded to html elements, pretty much MVVM.

The steps are something like this:

- start polling
- get full data
- convert the json into a javascript object
- update every html object tied to the data

The user can fire an event at any time and works with the latest updated local model.

- user fires event
- event + full data(all objects converted to json) is sent

Problems are: It's very rough and possibly slow, heavy on the client and the server.

My objectives are to reduce the data transfer to a minimum, and avoid client side corruption/attacks.
How should i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

> My objectives are to reduce the data transfer to a minimum

Send only the data that's changed, but the highest cost in AJAX is the request, so unless you are sending a lot of data, it may not make any noticeable difference.

> and avoid client side corruption/attacks

Impossible. Your code is running in a browser, the user can do whatever they want.

Answer (score 0):

> My objectives are to reduce the data transfer to a minimum

Some things to try:

- Reduce the number or frequency of client events that send an update
- Send only what data has changed
- Compress the data you send
- bundle several events into a single request

> and avoid client side corruption/attacks.

- To avoid attacks, you need to validate all input on the server. You should write your validator *without knowledge of the client*. You can assume nothing about what combination of data you can get--instead you should assume that someone is hand-crafting requests with a text editor and sending them with CURL.
- To avoid corruption (really a "lost update"), use [conditional PUTs or POSTs](http://www.w3.org/1999/04/Editing/) with the `if-none-match` or `if-unmodified-since` headers.